# Port Forwarding on Huawei E5885LS-93A doesn't work

Tags: networking, ip, router, port-forwarding, unifi

My home network is composed of a 4G router (Huawei E5885LS-93A) and three Ubiquiti Access Points (UAP-AC-M).
Within my network I run ZoneMinder on a Raspberry Pi 4.

From within my network I can just connect to ZoneMinder via `192.168.8.142:80/zm`, this works as expected.

I also want to connect to ZoneMinder from outside of my network.
Therefore I tried to create a port forwarding on the Huawei router: [Port forwarding on Huawei router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6XDb.png)

I found my public IP and tried to connect to `<my public ip>:80/zm`, but this doesn't work. I also checked https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/, and there it says port 80 is closed.
There is also a Unifi Controller running on a different Raspberry Pi on port 8443, but I can't connect to that either.

To my understanding the Huawei router is responsible for the port forwarding, but nonetheless I tried to setup port forwarding on the Unifi Controller with no success.

How can I setup port forwarding properly?